# In PHP, I encoded a JSON array from mySQL, how do I use it? decode?

Tags: php, mysql, json

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `scripts` LIMIT 0, 30 ";   
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ('Error updating database: ' . mysql_error()); 
$json = array(); 
if(mysql_num_rows($result)) { 
    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)) { 
        $json['table data'][]=$row;
    } 
 } 
$encoded = json_encode($json); 
echo $encoded;
```

This is my output:

```
{"table data":[["1","test","30","13"],["2","test2","40","14"]]}
```

How do I access an individual piece of the array, its an array of arrays? do i decode it first?

Comment: where do you wanna use it?

Comment: Why are you encoding it in the first place?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! On a side note; [please, don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1190388) in new code. They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the red box? Learn about prepared statements instead, and use [tag:PDO] or [tag:MySQLi].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you use

```
 $json['table data'][$id]
```

where $id is the row you want to access

so for example

```
$json['table data'][0][1]  == "test"
$json['table data'][1][1]  == "test2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to decode

```
$json = '{"foo-bar": 12345}';

$obj = json_decode($json);
print $obj->{'foo-bar'}; // 12345
```

Bye Bye

Answer (score 0):

Create an array, when you add data into array.

```
$json['table data'][] = array($row);
```